# Cleveref not making links: How to link theorem, etc?

Tags: hyperref, cleveref

The example below may not be exactly "minimal" because I am not sure of any package interdependencies, and I want you to be able to see exactly what I'm doing.  Ideally, I would like all of "Definition 1.0.1" to be linked with a non-colored, non-underlined link that is mainly detectable when you put the mouse over it while viewing the PDF.  If only the number gets linked, that is good enough, but not as good.  I want the same thing when I refer to "Theorem 2.0.1."  When I use `\ref` there are no links, and switching to `\cref` only makes the unlinked question marks appear (indicated with green arrows).  Thank you for looking at this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newif\iffirst\firsttrue %
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[left=1.5in,right=1.5in,top=0.75in,bottom=.75in,centering,includeheadfoot]{geometry}


 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  THEOREM ENV's %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{defin}[thm]{Definition}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theoremsymbol{\textleaf}
\newtheorem*{proof}{\textsf{\underline{Proof.}}}[subsection]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\large{
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{First Fake Section}
\begin{defin}\label{def:DEF1}
    A definition is supposed to tell you what something means.  In this case, a definition is something I will want to link as a cross-referenced item later via the label.
\end{defin}

\section{Second Fake Section}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:THM1}
Even if I cite this with CREF later, there won't be the link I want.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
As in Definition \cref{def:DEF1}, this doesn't get linked.
\end{proof}


\section{Third Fake Section}
You can see that links are not happening for either Definition \cref{def:DEF1} or Theorem \cref{thm:THM1}.  For some reason, switching from REF to CREF just makes these question marks appear.
 
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must load `ntheorem` *before* `cleveref`. And to remove the `thref` option.

I made a few changes to your code, for instance commenting out `textcomp` that's no longer necessary; I commented `hidelinks` just for the picture below.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[
  left=1.5in,
  right=1.5in,
  top=0.75in,
  bottom=0.75in,
  centering,
  includeheadfoot
]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}    
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[amsmath, thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{centernot}
\usepackage{longtable}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[
  %hidelinks
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newif\iffirst\firsttrue %
\allowdisplaybreaks


 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  THEOREM ENV's %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{defin}[thm]{Definition}
\theoremheaderfont{\itshape}
\theoremsymbol{\textleaf}
\newtheorem*{proof}{\textsf{\underline{Proof.}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\section{First Fake Section}

\begin{defin}\label{def:DEF1}
A definition is supposed to tell you what something means.  
In this case, a definition is something I will want to link 
as a cross-referenced item later via the label.
\end{defin}

\section{Second Fake Section}

\begin{thm}\label{thm:THM1}
Even if I cite this with CREF later, there won't be the link I want.
\end{thm}

\begin{proof}
As in \Cref{def:DEF1}, this doesn't get linked.
\end{proof}


\section{Third Fake Section}
You can see that links are not happening for either 
\Cref{def:DEF1} or \Cref{thm:THM1}.  
 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I think I did not need `\usepackage{cleveref}` at all.  Moving `\usepackage{ntheorem}` above `\usepackage{hyperref}` and deleting `thref` did exactly what I wanted.